# Not Able to Create Files and Directories From a Dictionary

Tags: python

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why the text files `(thisdict[key])` are not creating inside each directory `(key)`

I can create the directories but the text files are not generating!

```
import os

parent_dir = "B:/PyTest/"
thisdict =  {
  "1.1": "1.1-text.txt",
  "1.2": "1.1-text.txt",
  "1.3": "1.1-text.txt"
}

for key in thisdict:
  directory = key
  path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
  if not os.path.exists(path):
      os.makedirs(path)
  f = open(thisdict[key], "w")
  f.write(thisdict[key])
  f.close()
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I guess you want: `f = open(os.path.join(path, thisdict[key]), "w")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error coming from the file path that using to create the file , you were not using the correct path

```
import os

parent_dir = "D:/PyTest/"
thisdict =  {
  "1.1": "1.1-text.txt",
  "1.2": "1.1-text.txt",
  "1.3": "1.1-text.txt"
}

for key in thisdict:
  directory = key
  path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
  if not os.path.exists(path):
      os.makedirs(path)
  file_path = os.path.join(path,thisdict[key])
  f = open(file_path, "w")
  f.write(thisdict[key])
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pathlib` library to make it easier.

```
from pathlib import Path

parent_dir = Path()
this_dict = {
    "1.1": "1.1-text.txt",
    "1.2": "1.1-text.txt",
    "1.3": "1.1-text.txt"
}

for key in this_dict:
    path = Path(parent_dir / key)
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(path / this_dict[key], 'w') as f:
        f.write(this_dict[key])
```